# How to show/hide div in a button

Tags: jquery, navigation, show-hide, mobile-devices

i use jquery slide toggle to show/hide a div when a bttn clicked. Is it possible to place the div IN THE BUTTON ? 
(I need this for beeing able to stick the navigation properly on the top of the page which is for mobile devices.)

The HTML

```
<div class="medianavbttn">Show Menu</div>

<div class="medianav">
    <ul id="medianav-links">
        <li class="current"><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Gallery Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The Script

```
<script>
$(".medianavbttn").on("click", function(){
    $(".medianav").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).text($(this).text() == "Show Menu" ? "Hide Menu" : "Show Menu");
});
</script>
```

The CSS

```
.medianavbttn {
position: relative;
display:block;
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
cursor: pointer;
}

.medianav {
position: relative;
display: none;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify about *in* the button? Would on-top of the button suffice?

Comment: You don't have a button in your HTML, you click on a DIV. You can certainly have one DIV inside another DIV.

Comment: you say that you want these to stick to the top of a page, so I guess the `div`s can be wrapped in another `div` so that it is easier to control them as a unit

Comment: Thanks for you all your questions and answers... see my solution here below, answered by Kevin Pei !

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? 
**JsFiddle**:http://jsfiddle.net/GGtkc/ 
**HTML**:

```
<div class="medianavbttn">
    <span class="showbutton">Show Menu</span>

<div class="medianav">
    <ul id="medianav-links">
        <li class="current"><a href="#section1">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Gallery Photos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".medianavbttn").on("click", function(){
    $(".medianav").slideToggle("slow");
    $(this).find('.showbutton').text($(this).find('.showbutton').text() == "Show Menu" ? "Hide Menu" : "Show Menu");
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot ! You can see it here : http://igorlaszlo.com/mobile.html (you must resize the browser window to min 320 x 480 px as it is for mobile devices - small screens). 
I wanted to vote for your answer but i do not have enough reputation to do it...
One thing has remained, i must check if the sticky effect works on mobiles or not :)